# Appium Inspector seeing everything as one big element for iOS

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to get pointed in the right direction on a issue I am facing. Appium Inspector is grouping all elements into 1 monolithic thing on iOS, rendering it useless as it cannot select specific elements. I am not seeing this issue on Android. Appium Inspector is able to select individual elements for automation. I am trying to get some ideas where to look in the code to fix this issue.

This is a react native app, being used to compile iOS and Android builds.

Please see screenshots below of both as an iOS and Android example:

**iOS Example:**
[image]

**Android Example:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue with a specific element: its child elements were integrated in their parent element along it accessibility id, name etc.

In my case, I was using browserstack and the problem were coming from their side. When I ran the appium inspector with a local Appium server on Mac with an ios simulator everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to change react native code:

1. <TouchableOpacity **accessible={false}**>
2. <Stack.Navigator **mode={'modal'}**>

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem that has been raised here: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/14825

One workaround listed there is to increase `snapshotMaxDepth` in Appium settings (which is equal to 50 by default):

```
"appium:settings[snapshotMaxDepth]": 70
```